# How to convert json to plain text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to convert JSON to plain text?

`{"Days":["is not a number"]}` to Days is not a number.

Here is the code:

```
$('.best_in_place').bind("ajax:error", function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {
  alert(error.responseText);
});
```

Comment: is it always a object with a `key-value` pair, and the value is a array with a length of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the response into JSON object and parse its key-value pair

```
var error = JSON.parse( error.responseText );
for( var name in error ) {
    console.log( name + " " + error[ name ] ); // Days is not a number
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're using jQuery, this might help:

```
var result = '';
$.each(error.responseText, function(key, value) {
    result += key + ' ' + value;
});
```

This will also work and can easily be adjusted if the response holds multiple key-value-pairs.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/MMEmP/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [json-to-plain-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-plain-text) npm module